# truncation while exporting data using BCP Utility, when comma is present in a column

Tags: export, bcp

I have a batch file which executes the below bcp utility command, which executes a procedure (contains simple select statement to get the data), to export data into .csv format. The fields are seperated by pipe "|" and this is already mentioned in the format file:

> bcp "EXEC " queryout "file_name" -c -f "format.fmt" -b "500" -T -s

When a column has a comma in its data, the data after the comma and the data present in the remaining columns are not being pulled into the .csv file.

Would be helpful if some one explained this weird act!! Thanks

Comment: can you show format file content?

Answer (score 0):

use [-t !#  -r$$##] instead of format file and try ,it will work